# Error installing Bugzilla on CentOS

Tags: centos, bugzilla

I have been trying to install Bugzilla on a CentOS EC2 instance for days now and I'm running into this error.  I have no idea what to do and Google is providing me no help. Can anyone point me in the right direction?  Output is derived from following command: `cpan> install DBD::mysql`

```
cpan[1]> install DBD::mysql
CPAN: Storable loaded ok (v2.20)
Going to read '/root/.cpan/Metadata'
  Database was generated on Fri, 27 Apr 2012 22:03:03 GMT
Running install for module 'DBD::mysql'
CPAN: YAML loaded ok (v0.81)
Running make for C/CA/CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-4.020.tar.gz
CPAN: Digest::SHA loaded ok (v5.47)
CPAN: Compress::Zlib loaded ok (v2.037)
Checksum for /root/.cpan/sources/authors/id/C/CA/CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-4.020.tar.gz ok
Scanning cache /root/.cpan/build for sizes
...................................................................---------DONE
DEL(1/30): /root/.cpan/build/DateTime-TimeZone-1.46-dGBCws 
DEL(2/30): /root/.cpan/build/Params-Util-1.07-bfhIz0 
DEL(3/30): /root/.cpan/build/Params-Util-1.07-bfhIz0.yml 
DEL(4/30): /root/.cpan/build/Sub-Install-0.926-zg2FZc 
DEL(5/30): /root/.cpan/build/Sub-Install-0.926-zg2FZc.yml 
DEL(6/30): /root/.cpan/build/Data-OptList-0.107-xuhpJu 
DEL(7/30): /root/.cpan/build/Data-OptList-0.107-xuhpJu.yml 
DEL(8/30): /root/.cpan/build/Sub-Exporter-0.982-TSCGF8 
DEL(9/30): /root/.cpan/build/Sub-Exporter-0.982-TSCGF8.yml 
DEL(10/30): /root/.cpan/build/Test-Tester-0.108-Elc5FP 
DEL(11/30): /root/.cpan/build/Test-Tester-0.108-Elc5FP.yml 
DEL(12/30): /root/.cpan/build/Test-Output-1.01-aPLGPN 
DEL(13/30): /root/.cpan/build/Test-Output-1.01-aPLGPN.yml 
DEL(14/30): /root/.cpan/build/parent-0.225-O4BnD5.yml 
DEL(15/30): /root/.cpan/build/parent-0.225-O4BnD5 
DEL(16/30): /root/.cpan/build/Class-Load-0.19-bQYHPa 
DEL(17/30): /root/.cpan/build/Dist-CheckConflicts-0.02-Muyn5_ 
DEL(18/30): /root/.cpan/build/Dist-CheckConflicts-0.02-Muyn5_.yml 
DEL(19/30): /root/.cpan/build/Package-Stash-0.33-pDnyqD 
DEL(20/30): /root/.cpan/build/Package-DeprecationManager-0.13-87YBY0 
DEL(21/30): /root/.cpan/build/Package-DeprecationManager-0.13-hsYDCP 
DEL(22/30): /root/.cpan/build/Package-DeprecationManager-0.13-hsYDCP.yml 
DEL(23/30): /root/.cpan/build/Package-Stash-XS-0.25-rntJPE.yml 
DEL(24/30): /root/.cpan/build/Package-Stash-XS-0.25-rntJPE 
DEL(25/30): /root/.cpan/build/Package-Stash-0.33-MPf9ps 
DEL(26/30): /root/.cpan/build/Package-Stash-0.33-MPf9ps.yml 
DEL(27/30): /root/.cpan/build/Class-Load-0.19-uxaOTg 
DEL(28/30): /root/.cpan/build/Class-Load-0.19-uxaOTg.yml 
DEL(29/30): /root/.cpan/build/Class-Singleton-1.4-LmzAhH 
DEL(30/30): /root/.cpan/build/Class-Singleton-1.4-LmzAhH.yml 
DBD-mysql-4.020/
DBD-mysql-4.020/ChangeLog
DBD-mysql-4.020/constants.h
DBD-mysql-4.020/dbdimp.c
DBD-mysql-4.020/dbdimp.h
DBD-mysql-4.020/eg/
DBD-mysql-4.020/eg/bug14979.pl
DBD-mysql-4.020/eg/bug21028.pl
DBD-mysql-4.020/eg/bug30033.pl
DBD-mysql-4.020/eg/bug30033pg.pl
DBD-mysql-4.020/eg/decimal_test.pl
DBD-mysql-4.020/eg/issue21946.pl
DBD-mysql-4.020/eg/prepare_memory_usage.pl
DBD-mysql-4.020/eg/proc_example1.pl
DBD-mysql-4.020/eg/proc_example2.pl
DBD-mysql-4.020/eg/proc_example2a.pl
DBD-mysql-4.020/eg/proc_example2b.pl
DBD-mysql-4.020/eg/proc_example3.pl
DBD-mysql-4.020/eg/proc_example4.pl
DBD-mysql-4.020/INSTALL.html
DBD-mysql-4.020/lib/
DBD-mysql-4.020/lib/Bundle/
DBD-mysql-4.020/lib/Bundle/DBD/
DBD-mysql-4.020/lib/Bundle/DBD/mysql.pm
DBD-mysql-4.020/lib/DBD/
DBD-mysql-4.020/lib/DBD/mysql/
DBD-mysql-4.020/lib/DBD/mysql/GetInfo.pm
DBD-mysql-4.020/lib/DBD/mysql/INSTALL.pod
DBD-mysql-4.020/lib/DBD/mysql.pm
DBD-mysql-4.020/Makefile.PL
DBD-mysql-4.020/Makefile.PL.embedded
DBD-mysql-4.020/MANIFEST
DBD-mysql-4.020/MANIFEST.SKIP
DBD-mysql-4.020/META.yml
DBD-mysql-4.020/myld
DBD-mysql-4.020/mysql.xs
DBD-mysql-4.020/README
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/00base.t
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/10connect.t
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/20createdrop.t
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/25lockunlock.t
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/29warnings.t
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/30insertfetch.t
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/31insertid.t
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/32insert_error.t
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/35limit.t
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/35prepare.t
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/40bindparam.t
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/40bindparam2.t
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/40blobs.t
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/40catalog.t
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/40keyinfo.t
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/40listfields.t
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/40nulls.t
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/40nulls_prepare.t
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/40numrows.t
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/40server_prepare.t
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/40server_prepare_error.t
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/40types.t
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/41bindparam.t
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/41blobs_prepare.t
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/42bindparam.t
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/50chopblanks.t
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/50commit.t
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/51bind_type_guessing.t
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/52comment.t
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/53comment.t
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/55utf8.t
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/60leaks.t
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/65types.t
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/70takeimp.t
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/71impdata.t
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/75supported_sql.t
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/76multi_statement.t
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/80procs.t
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/85init_command.t
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/86_bug_36972.t
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/lib.pl
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/mem_leak.pl
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/mysql.dbtest
DBD-mysql-4.020/t/mysql.mtest
DBD-mysql-4.020/TODO
CPAN: File::Temp loaded ok (v0.22)

  CPAN.pm: Going to build C/CA/CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-4.020.tar.gz



PLEASE NOTE:

For 'make test' to run properly, you must ensure that the 
database user 'root' can connect to your MySQL server 
and has the proper privileges that these tests require such 
as 'drop table', 'create table', 'drop procedure', 'create procedure'
as well as others. 

mysql> grant all privileges on test.* to 'root'@'localhost' identified by 's3kr1t';

You can also optionally set the user to run 'make test' with:

perl Makefile.PL --testuser=username

I will use the following settings for compiling and testing:

  cflags        (mysql_config) = -I/usr/include/mysql55 -g -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fPIC  -fPIC -g -static-libgcc -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -DMY_PTHREAD_FASTMUTEX=1
  embedded      (mysql_config) = 
  libs          (mysql_config) = -L/usr/lib64/mysql -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -lrt -lssl -lcrypto -ldl
  mysql_config  (guessed     ) = mysql_config
  nocatchstderr (default     ) = 0
  nofoundrows   (default     ) = 0
  ssl           (guessed     ) = 1
  testdb        (default     ) = test
  testhost      (default     ) = 
  testpassword  (default     ) = 
  testsocket    (default     ) = 
  testuser      (guessed     ) = root

To change these settings, see 'perl Makefile.PL --help' and
'perldoc INSTALL'.

Checking if your kit is complete...
Looks good
Multiple copies of Driver.xst found in: /usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/DBI/ /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/auto/DBI/ at Makefile.PL line 928
Using DBI 1.620 (for perl 5.010001 on x86_64-linux-thread-multi) installed in /usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/DBI/
Writing Makefile for DBD::mysql
Writing MYMETA.yml and MYMETA.json
cp lib/DBD/mysql.pm blib/lib/DBD/mysql.pm
cp lib/DBD/mysql/GetInfo.pm blib/lib/DBD/mysql/GetInfo.pm
cp lib/DBD/mysql/INSTALL.pod blib/lib/DBD/mysql/INSTALL.pod
cp lib/Bundle/DBD/mysql.pm blib/lib/Bundle/DBD/mysql.pm
gcc -c  -I/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/DBI -I/usr/include/mysql55 -g -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fPIC  -fPIC -g -static-libgcc -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -DMY_PTHREAD_FASTMUTEX=1 -DDBD_MYSQL_WITH_SSL -DDBD_MYSQL_INSERT_ID_IS_GOOD -g  -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic   -DVERSION=\"4.020\" -DXS_VERSION=\"4.020\" -fPIC "-I/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE"   dbdimp.c
dbdimp.c: In function ‘dbd_discon_all’:
dbdimp.c:2193: warning: unused variable ‘imp_xxh’
dbdimp.c: In function ‘mysql_db_STORE_attrib’:
dbdimp.c:2383: warning: value computed is not used
dbdimp.c: In function ‘mysql_db_FETCH_attrib’:
dbdimp.c:2495: warning: value computed is not used
dbdimp.c:2502: warning: value computed is not used
dbdimp.c: In function ‘mysql_st_prepare’:
dbdimp.c:2614: warning: unused variable ‘limit_flag’
dbdimp.c: In function ‘mysql_st_next_results’:
dbdimp.c:3038: warning: value computed is not used
dbdimp.c:3039: warning: value computed is not used
dbdimp.c:3040: warning: value computed is not used
dbdimp.c:3041: warning: value computed is not used
dbdimp.c:3042: warning: value computed is not used
dbdimp.c:3043: warning: value computed is not used
dbdimp.c:3044: warning: value computed is not used
dbdimp.c:3045: warning: value computed is not used
dbdimp.c:3046: warning: value computed is not used
dbdimp.c:3047: warning: value computed is not used
dbdimp.c:3048: warning: value computed is not used
dbdimp.c:3049: warning: value computed is not used
dbdimp.c:3050: warning: value computed is not used
dbdimp.c:3051: warning: value computed is not used
dbdimp.c:3052: warning: value computed is not used
dbdimp.c:3053: warning: value computed is not used
dbdimp.c:3054: warning: value computed is not used
dbdimp.c:3055: warning: value computed is not used
dbdimp.c: In function ‘mysql_st_FETCH_attrib’:
dbdimp.c:4429: warning: value computed is not used
/usr/bin/perl -p -e "s/~DRIVER~/mysql/g" /usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/DBI/Driver.xst > mysql.xsi
/usr/bin/perl /usr/share/perl5/ExtUtils/xsubpp  -typemap /usr/share/perl5/ExtUtils/typemap  mysql.xs > mysql.xsc && mv mysql.xsc mysql.c
Warning: duplicate function definition 'do' detected in mysql.xs, line 242
Warning: duplicate function definition 'rows' detected in mysql.xs, line 751
gcc -c  -I/usr/local/lib64/perl5/auto/DBI -I/usr/include/mysql55 -g -pipe -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -D_GNU_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -fPIC  -fPIC -g -static-libgcc -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-strict-aliasing -DMY_PTHREAD_FASTMUTEX=1 -DDBD_MYSQL_WITH_SSL -DDBD_MYSQL_INSERT_ID_IS_GOOD -g  -D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic   -DVERSION=\"4.020\" -DXS_VERSION=\"4.020\" -fPIC "-I/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE"   mysql.c
mysql.xs: In function ‘XS_DBD__mysql__db_do’:
mysql.xs:307: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘struct SV *’
mysql.xs:309: warning: value computed is not used
mysql.xs:260: warning: unused variable ‘statement_ptr’
mysql.xs: In function ‘XS_DBD__mysql__st_more_results’:
mysql.xs:689: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘mysql_st_next_results’
mysql.xs:688: warning: unused variable ‘retval’
mysql.xs: In function ‘XS_DBD__mysql__GetInfo_dbd_mysql_get_info’:
mysql.xs:899: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘is_prefix’
Running Mkbootstrap for DBD::mysql ()
chmod 644 mysql.bs
rm -f blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so
LD_RUN_PATH="/usr/lib64/mysql:/lib64:/usr/lib64" /usr/bin/perl myld gcc  -shared -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic dbdimp.o mysql.o  -o blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so     \
       -L/usr/lib64/mysql -lmysqlclient -lpthread -lz -lm -lrt -lssl -lcrypto -ldl      \

chmod 755 blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so
cp mysql.bs blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bs
chmod 644 blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bs
Manifying blib/man3/DBD::mysql.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/DBD::mysql::INSTALL.3pm
Manifying blib/man3/Bundle::DBD::mysql.3pm
  CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-4.020.tar.gz
  make -- OK
Running make test
PERL_DL_NONLAZY=1 /usr/bin/perl "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0, 'blib/lib', 'blib/arch')" t/*.t
t/00base.t .................. 1/6 
#   Failed test 'use DBD::mysql;'
#   at t/00base.t line 21.
#     Tried to use 'DBD::mysql'.
#     Error:  Can't load '/root/.cpan/build/DBD-mysql-4.020-jWcDi9/blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so' for module DBD::mysql: /root/.cpan/build/DBD-mysql-4.020-jWcDi9/blib/arch/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.so: undefined symbol: is_prefix at /usr/lib64/perl5/DynaLoader.pm line 200.
#  at (eval 7) line 2
# Compilation failed in require at (eval 7) line 2.
# BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at (eval 7) line 2.
Bailout called.  Further testing stopped:  Unable to load DBD::mysql
FAILED--Further testing stopped: Unable to load DBD::mysql
make: *** [test_dynamic] Error 255
  CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-4.020.tar.gz
  make test -- NOT OK
//hint// to see the cpan-testers results for installing this module, try:
  reports CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-4.020.tar.gz
Running make install
  make test had returned bad status, won't install without force
Failed during this command:
 CAPTTOFU/DBD-mysql-4.020.tar.gz              : make_test NO
```

Comment: A suggestion - install your Perl modules using yum to the extent possible - it is much faster and easier than cpan if you don't need the most up to date version of a module. `yum install perl-DBD-MySQL` (and if some of the modules aren't in the core CentOS repository, add the [EPEL](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repository). It actually looks like make succeeded, but make test failed - possibly because of problems with MySQL authentication (can you login to MySQL with the username/password you passed to the test script, and does that user have the needed permissions?)

Answer (score 0):

Bugzilla is in the [EPEL repository](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL). Install that first (every CentOS system eventually seems to need something from it) and then install bugzilla using yum.

```
yum install bugzilla
```